# Требуется пояснение по регулярке JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

В общем у меня есть форма, я чищу строку по шаблонурегуляркой, как задать что бы если не "чистится" то подсвечивалось?

```
var name=$('#inputregName').val().match(/\D+/gi).join('');
```

Здесь когда не подходит выдает null и начинает ругаться. Не могу понять как по нормальному делают форму. 
Буду благодарен за совет или пример.

Comment: делайте `join('')` после проверки есть ли что-то после `match()`, ибо null не имеет метода `join()`

Comment: @ MedvedevDev Спасибо бро !)